# How does React.useState fire the containing function again?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

Say we have a simple functional component:

```
export function MyComp(){

   const [state, setState] = React.useState({foo:1});

   setTimeout(() => setState({foo:2}, 45);

   return (
    <div> {state.foo} </div>
   )

}
```

How would it re-render if `setState` didn't magically call `MyComp()` again? And if it magically calls `MyComp()` again, how does that work?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `setState` does not magically call your component but triggers a re-render. Therefore, doing `setState(someValue)` in your case is what causes `MyComp` to re-render. You can read more about this and hooks in the React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#recap

Hope it answers your question!

Comment: sorry but it does not answer the question - MyComp() must get called to make the re-render happen, but given the rules of JS, it's unclear how that happens

Comment: The re-rendering is handled internally by React. If you want to learn more about the process, I suggest reading this article: https://medium.com/the-guild/under-the-hood-of-reacts-hooks-system-eb59638c9dba

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on the mechanism itself on React, but the idea behind it in a very simplified version using some CS concepts could be as follows:

First off, React has to have a list of all components in your app, we will simplify it with a list but it is in reality a tree:

```
const nodes = <>
  <h1>My Counter</h1>
  <Counter />
  <div>
</>
```

So at this point, if your application were flat, a `DummyReactDOM.render(nodes)` would create a list of these nodes":

```
nodes = [ h1, Counter, div ]
```

It gets tricky when `useState` is called, and what React will do is saved some sort of state (memoized state), for example the `Counter` node may look like this:

```
function Counter() {
  [ counter, setCounter ] = useState(0);
}
```

This will add a state to the node:

```
node Counter = {
  state : {
    counter: 0
    next  : null
  }
}
```

Now, what happens when we click on the component and call `setCounter(counter + 1)` ? A *next* state is added to the queue:

```
node Counter = {
  state : {
    counter : 0,
    next    : {
      state : {
        counter : 1, // <-- setCounter(counter + 1 happens)
        next    : null,
      }
    }
  }
}

// firstState.next -> secondState.next -> null
```

Now, a *scheduler* here is the master mind of knowing which components needs to be re-rendered. Here's a very unrealistic but easy-to-digest way of seeing it:

```
while (true) {

  // sleepForABit();

  if (currentNode.state.next !== null && currentNode.state !== currentNode.state.next) {
    currentNode.state = currentNode.state.next;
    currentNode.component.render(); // or functionalComponent() call
  }

  currentNode = currentNode.next
}
```

This is a simple case if it were a list of nodes, but obviously as a node needs to be re-rendered, React will check on its children. It's important to note that re-rendering is not really that expensive, the expensive part is re-creating DOM nodes (and, to a lesser extent, updating them), hence it is mostly quite performant to check on the child nodes.

Hope this helps!

In case you are wondering why we can do `setCounter(counter + 1)` without having `counter = 0` always, React guarantees that nodes are re-rendered on certain events (`onClick` being one of the many).

Comment: in a class based component `render()` would get called again I assume if state changes. so in a functional "component", I would assume that function gets called again when the state changes? that was my original assumption but I guess it's wrong?

Comment: For a class component, the `render()` as well as other lifecycle methods such as `componentDidUpdate` will get called indeed. For functional components, the whole function gets called, there is no other way. That's why hooks exists, for example, `useEffect`'s code will not be run again if certain values don't change.